# SVG path (ellipse) fill with image does not work (except Chrome on MacOS)

Tags: html, svg, user-agent, fill

Created a simple SVG with an ellipse. I want that ellipse to get filled with an external image. It shows OK on Chrome on MacOS but on no other agent. What is wrong ?
Searched a lot of other questions here but none is helpful, it seems.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tagtag/pen/jKerRx)

```html
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  x="100px" y="100px" viewBox="0 0 177.5 175" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="200" width="200">
      <image x="100" y="1000" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7Nlcay7.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
 <ellipse id="FillThisWithColorOrPattern" style="fill:url(#image)" stroke="#333333" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="90" cy="87" rx="87.5" ry="82"/>
<circle id="Inner_1_" fill="#FF0000" cx="90" cy="87" r="35"/>
 <path id="TextLine1_Path" fill=None        
  d="M90,137.5c-27.8,0-50.5-22.7-50.5-50.5S62.2,36.5,90,36.5s50.5,22.7,50.5,50.5S117.8,137.5,90,137.5z M90,37.5
  c-27.3,0-49.5,22.2-49.5,49.5s22.2,49.5,49.5,49.5c27.3,0,49.5-22.2,49.5-49.5S117.3,37.5,90,37.5z"/>
   <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#TextLine1_Path">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to specify a width and a height to your image for other browsers. I tried with Firefox 58 and Safari 11 on MacOS and the pattern is there.

```
<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7Nlcay7.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
```

Here's your example updated: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJeMda

Also, note that `xlink:href` is deprecated since SVG 2. You should now use `href`. The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) adds:

> For browsers implementing href, if both href and xlink:href are set, xlink:href will be ignored and only href will be used.

Comment: Safari doesn't support href, only xlink:href last I checked.

Comment: @RobertLongson This is why one should put both "xlink:href" and "href".